# How can I store the answers from a while loop into a dataframe or table

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, while-loop, store

I've written the following loop:

```
i<-1
j<-100

while(i < 1501)
{
    finalmean<-mean(all_the_means[i:j])
    i<-i+100
    j<-j+100
    print(finalmean)
}
```

I get 15 answers, but I'm unable to store them into a `dataframe`. if I do type `data.frame(finalmean)`, it just shows me the last value that I get in the loop, which is `NA`. How can I store all the 15 answers into a table?

Comment: What programming language is this?

Comment: sorry, completely forgot to mention that. This is R.